# Accessing oracle database from c# with odb.net

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oracle11g, odp.net

I'm trying to access Oracle 11g DB.
According to connectionstring.com , the connstring should be :

```
Driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};Dbq=myTNSServiceName;Uid=user;Pwd=passwd;
```

Anyhow I'm getting an ArgumentException:  'Driver' is not a valid word.

Thank you.

Greetings

R. Bada

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are trying to use connection string which is suitable in case of ODBC drivers for Oracle.

You should look for connection string suitable for ODP.NET in [Oracle Data Provider for .NET / ODP.NET](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle#oracle-data-provider-for-net-odp-net) section. The best is to use one of the following:

```
Data Source=TNSServiceName;User Id=user;Password=passwd;
```

or

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));User Id=user;Password=passwd;
```

The first is suitable when you are using TNS, the second allows you to provide the service definition in connection string.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have no tnsnamesnames file... So I would like to describe the service. But what should I put in MyOracleSID?

Comment: @user897237 The service_name may or may not be the ORACLE_SID. It is setup via the init.ora file with the "service_names" parameter. You can check this parameter by: `select name, value from v$parameters where name like 'service%`. Also remember that in case of second connection string other forms of Oracle Host String are acceptable.